# Databinding to an ObservableCollection of unknown object type

Tags: wpf, data-binding, types, user-controls

In my main project I have an `ObservableCollection<DataValue>`, where `DataValue` is a type from a 3rd party library, and it looks like this (simplified):

```
public class DataValue : IFormattable, ICloneable
{
    private object m_value;
    private TypeInfo m_typeInfo;

    public object Value
    {
        get { return this.m_value; }
    }

    public TypeInfo TypeInfo
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.m_typeInfo == (TypeInfo) null)
              return TypeInfo.Unknown;
            else
              return this.m_typeInfo;
        }
    }
}
```

In a different project in my solution I have a view and viewmodel to display the data in this collection, and it works fine when binding to a `ListBox` (it correctly displays the value, if the `DataValue.Value` is an `integer`, a `byte[]` or whatever), so it somehow figures out of the actual type automatically?

I want the same behavior in a custom control I have created, and if the value is a collection of `byte[]`, it should process the data.

How can I accomplish this? I tried fooling around with a ValueConverter and some reflection and casting, but it seems unnecessary since the native controls seem to figure this out automatically.

Comment: I think the native controls "figure it out" by calling `ToString()`.

Comment: What happens when you bind your custom control ? Is the data binding happening at all?